# last character is missing from every single cell value in import file using php-excel-reader

Tags: php, excel, phpexcelreader

I am using php-excel-reader library for import data from xls file. I am exporting **xls file from CRM** and when I upload it to server for import data **php-excel-reader** read every single cell value but I am not getting last character of string(cellvalue). Excel sheet contains special spanish character. I used `iconv()` and `utf8_encode()` for solve this issue but I'm still facing same issue.

Output : (**Uploaded directly exported file**)

```
[20] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 34
            [2] => De León Cantú, Alons
            [3] => 8358-380
            [4] => 09:00 PM - 09:00 AM 12/0
            [5] => 33
            [6] => 
            [7] => Campos Duque, Maria del Rosari
            [8] => (81) 8688-863
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
        )
```

Other scenario : when I open xls file exported from CRM and when I save it as **Save As**, it's working. I don't know how this is happening?

Output : (**Open and Save As before upload file**)

```
[20] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 34
        [2] => De León Cantú, Alonso
        [3] => 8358-3807
        [4] => 09:00 PM - 09:00 AM 12/02
        [5] => 33
        [6] => 
        [7] => Campos Duque, Maria del Rosario
        [8] => (81) 8688-8632
    )
```

This is code which I have used to read xls file.

**Code :**

```
    $xl_reader = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $xl_reader->read("reports.xls");

    for($i=0;$i<$xl_reader->sheets[0]['numRows'];$i++) {
        for($j=0;$j<$xl_reader->sheets[0]['numCols'];$j++){
            if(!empty($xl_reader->sheets[0]['cells'][$i+1])){
                $file_data[$i][$j] = $xl_reader->sheets[0]['cells'][$i+1][$j+1];
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($file_data);
    exit;
```

Comment: Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader !== PHPExcel

Comment: I know how improbable this is but. Any chances there's a solution to this issue?